# Atoms vs molecule when talking about the avogadro's number?

Tags: atoms, molecules, mole

By far, my understanding is that a molecule is made up of atoms bonded together. For example, a molecule of water ($\ce{H2O}$) has 2 hydrogen atoms and one oxygen atom.

However, when it comes to Avogadro's number, I'm getting confused because it mixes the concept and treats it like it is the same.

> Avogadro's number is defined as the number of elementary particles (molecules, atoms, compounds, etc.) per mole of a substance.

If I take 1 mole of water, with the molecules definition for the Avogadro's number, it has $ \mathrm{6.022×10^{23}} $ molecules of water. With each molecule having 3 atoms, it means that 1 mole of water has $\mathrm{18.066×10^{23}} $ atoms.

If I take 1 mole of water with the atoms definition for Avogadro's number, it has $\mathrm{6.022×10^{23}}$ atoms of water.

What is the right way to think about this?

Comment: A mole is always just a number. Out of context that means you don't know what you are *counting*. You always need to define exactly *what* is being counted. This resolves the ambiguity (one mole of water *molecules* contains one mole of oxygen *atoms* but also two moles of hydrogen *atoms*: there is no ambiguity if the thing being counted is specified.)

Comment: The Avogadro number is just a number, like 12. You can have 12 eggs, or 12 boxes of eggs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$1$ mole of water has $\pu{6.022E23}$ molecules of water, but not $\pu{6.022E23}$ atoms of water, because the expression "atoms of water" has no sense. You are allowed to state that it contains $\pu{18.066E23}$ atoms. But you are not allowed to speak of "atoms of water". Water has not its own atoms of water.